# Chrome ignoring <source> a picture/source/img construction

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome version 111.0.5563.111 on Windows is not loading the Webp image, nor the Png image. It would appear that it's ignoring the source tag altogether. If the img tag is removed, no picture is shown.

What gives?

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png" alt="Image" class="tm-img">
</picture>
```

Comment: It would appear that if no <img> tag is included in the construct, Chrome wont show any image at all. Also, Chrome's inspector will highlight the image object only when clicking on <img>, which contains the fallback image, however the image URL being loaded is indeed the WebP one from <source>. Misleading.